# Hessian matrix for extremum

Tags: calculus, analysis, hessian-matrix

Is it enough to say a function doesn't have an extremum at a point if the determinant of the Hessian at that point is smaller than 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true in two dimensions, but not in general. In 3D for example the function
$$
f(x,y,z)=-x^2-y^2-z^2
$$
has negative Hessian everywhere and clearly has a local (and global) maximum at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

If the space has even dimension, then symmetric semidefinite matrices all have determinant $\ge0$, and therefore a singular point with Hessian of negative determinant must be a saddle point. In odd dimension consider the map $-\frac12x^\top x$ which has a maximum in $0$.